# Dual boot extend partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I am really new to ubuntu, and I wanted to extend my dual boot Ubuntu partition, but there is no option to which I can extend it.

I have run *gparted*, then I *swapoff* the **linux-swap.** I already have an unallocated space but the resize function is not extendable. What I wanted is to resize the ubuntu hdd which I think is **dev/sda6**.

**Here is the image:**
[image]

**When clicking resize:**
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help. Hope you could guide me, because I dont to ruin my boot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it's a long tricky process..you have to shift the sda3 partition to the end (it takes a while and DO NOT STOP the process if you're getting bored ^_^)
after that you can resize your sda6 partition

Comment: How long will it take for all the unallocated?

Comment: there are 2 factors..occupied space to shift (in your case 291GB..which are a lot) and quality of the HDD. Making a guess..3 to 6 hours..

Comment: I got an error windows failed to start. help.

Comment: sometimes it occurs..no panic..use your Windows CD and follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/) guide

Comment: It was successful. But I cant seem to drag it.